# Multiple maven modules to separate tests, api and implementation

Tags: java, maven, junit

I want to create a maven project with several implementations in separate modules of several interfaces declared in one **api** module (for the context, I'm writing a java persistence labs where students has to implement several time the services and repositories starting from simple JDBC to JPA then spring-data-jpa).

There is several maven modules in the project:

- the root maven `multiple-modules` module, including the three submodules
- the `api` module, containing the API interfaces
- the `api-tests` module, containing the tests related to the API interfaces
- the `main` module, containing one of the implementation of API

### Root project module

The main maven project declares three submodules:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
             http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.kartoch.stack</groupId>
    <artifactId>multiple-modules</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <modules>
        <module>api</module>
        <module>main</module>
        <module>tests</module>
    </modules>

</project>
```

### API module

The API declares the interface:

```
public interface MustReturnTrue {

    boolean askMeTrue();
}
```

The related `pom.xml` of the api submodule:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
              http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>multiple-modules</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.kartoch.stack</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <artifactId>api</artifactId>


</project>
```

### Tests module

In this module, tests are wrote against the API interface:

```
import org.junit.Test;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

public class MustReturnTrueTest extends Template {


    @Test
    public void testAskMeTrue() {
        assertTrue(mustReturnTrue.askMeTrue());
    }
}
```

Because the implementation of the API interface is submodule-dependant, an abstract class is available in the test package, and need to be implemented in each implementation module:

```
public abstract class Template {

    public MustReturnTrue mustReturnTrue;
}
```

For both classes, the code is in `src/main/java` directory and not `src/test/java` directory as I use [**the preferred way** to create a jar containing test classes](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/examples/create-test-jar.html):

The related `pom.xml` of the tests submodule.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
              http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>multiple-modules</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.kartoch.stack</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <artifactId>api-tests</artifactId>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.kartoch.stack</groupId>
            <artifactId>api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

### Main module

Finally, the main module contains one implementation of the API interfaces (in `src/main/java`):

public class MustReturnTrueImpl implements MustReturnTrue {
    public boolean askMeTrue() {
        return true;
    }
}

And the template implementation for test (in `src/test/java`):

```
import org.junit.Before;

public class TemplateInitialization extends Template {

    @Before
    public void before() {
        mustReturnTrue = new MustReturnTrueImpl();
    }
}
```

The related `pom.xml` of the main submodule:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>multiple-modules</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.kartoch.stack</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <artifactId>main</artifactId>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.kartoch.stack</groupId>
            <artifactId>api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.kartoch.stack</groupId>
            <artifactId>api-tests</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

### The problem

What I expect during tests is that the tests in the tests module are executed against the implementation after initialization of the implementation by the class implementing `Template`.

But for unknown reason the tests are not executed during `main` test lifecycle:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

Any idea ?

### Edit 1

I've the impression that the problem is the heriting is not working as expected. As `TemplateInitialization` is heriting Template which contains no tests, there is no tests executed: tests in `MustReturnTrueTest` are not "magically" imported. I need a way to  load the TemplateInitialization at runtime before the tests.

Comment: I've added the full project in github: https://github.com/kartoch/so-mutiple

Comment: Why do you've put tests into separate module? It it is an api tests put them into api module.

Comment: A test should be named like `WhatEverTest.java` (see docs for maven-surefire-plugin..)...and not `TemplateInitialization ` ...so just name it `TemplateInitializationTest.java`...

Comment: @AleksandrM yes, that's a good idea

Comment: @khmarbaise This class is not a test but just initialize the template. Even when renaming it does not work

Comment: try to extends MustReturnTrueTest in TemplateInitialization

Answer (score 1):

Your template initialization should be done directly in the test class:

```
import org.junit.Test;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

public class MustReturnTrueTest extends Template {

    @Before
    public void before() {
        mustReturnTrue = new MustReturnTrueImpl();
    }

    @Test
    public void testAskMeTrue() {
        assertTrue(mustReturnTrue.askMeTrue());
    }
}
```

If you need an instanciation before each test, use the JUnit `@Before` annotation.

If you need the instanciation to happen once, before all the tests in the test class, use `@BeforeClass`.

---

Edit:

And I would advise you to put the tests along the implementation code (in the main project), as per Maven standards.

Answer (score -1):

In maven standard tests are written in the tested project, end respect some notation : http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html

```
 <build>
    <directory>target</directory>
    <outputDirectory>target/classes</outputDirectory>
    <finalName>${artifactId}-${version}</finalName>
    <testOutputDirectory>target/test-classes</testOutputDirectory>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
    <scriptSourceDirectory>src/main/scripts</scriptSourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <testResources>
      <testResource>
        <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
      </testResource>
    </testResources>
  </build>
```

So if you do not want override default pom configuration you have to implement test in src/test/java in your **tests** module

Comment: I'm using this way for creating my tests and include them in the main module: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/examples/create-test-jar.html